Simple membership registration form submit button is not working also not adding the new user record in simple membership members list
In Simple membership plugin i get the unique registration form link in the email but when i registered the user using the registration form and putting the email and password and when i hit submit button then the record is not added in the members list. I don't know why it not storing the new record in the members list. please help and guide me to fix this issue.
I want registration form's submit button should work properly and it also save the record in simple membership members list

Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others to provide an answer faster.
